# How to Dynamically select the path to System folder based on 32/64 bit OS with Puppet

Tags: windows, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am automating the deployment of my web application on Windows 2008 server R2 using Puppet.

There are several steps in which I would be accessing the System folder (System32 or SysWOW64 depending on 32/64 bit OS).

Let me take one of these steps: I would access 'appcmd.exe' to Start/Stop website. When the script is running on 32-bit machine, I need to access the file at `'C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv/appcmd.exe'` and when the script is running on a 64-bit machine, I need to access the file at `'C:/Windows/SysWOW64/inetsrv/appcmd.exe'`

Here is the part of the script that I have written. I do not want to hard-code the path. Depending the OS, i want the path to 'appcmd.exe' to be chosen. How can I achieve this?

`exec {"StopWebsite":
 command=> 'C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv/appcmd.exe stop site /site.name:"Default Web Site"' 
}`

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_conditional.html#case-statements

Comment: Also https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to throw you off too much, but have you looked at the [puppet-iis](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppet/iis) module (formerly OpenTable's IIS module)?

#### How to Use the 32-bit application (if available)

To answer your question, this is the first time I've heard of a request to get to the 32-bit apps. The following should work with 32 or 64 bit Puppet on both 32 and 64 bit Operating Systems:

```
exec {'StopWebsite': 
  path    => 'C:/Windows/SysWOW64/inetsrv;C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv',
  command => 'appcmd.exe stop site /site.name:"Default Web Site"',
}
```

It works because it checks for the command in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` first before moving on to `C:\Windows\system32`. This allows it to fall through to the correct 32-bit `appcmd.exe` when it runs.

#### How to Use the 64-bit application (if available)

For others, if you are always trying to get to the 64 bit processes and your on Puppet 3.7.3 or later, use the [$system32](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_windows_file_paths.html#file-system-redirection-when-running-32-bit-puppet-on-64-bit-windows) fact. This works no matter if you are using a 64-bit or 32-bit version of Puppet.

```
exec {'somefunction': 
  command => "$system32\\cmd.exe /c some command",
}
```

Or you can also try the opposite trick, set the path order so that it will get sysnative first with a fallback to system32.

```
exec {'somefunction': 
  path    => 'C:/Windows/sysnative;C:/Windows/System32',
  command => 'cmd.exe /c some command',
}
```

#### Keep the Rest of the Path Intact

If you need to keep the rest of the path, just append [`$path`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.3/core_facts.html#path) to the end of the string, but specify it with double quotes:

```
path => "C:\\Windows\\sysnative;C:\\Windows\\System32;$::path",
```

You will probably be fine with forward slashes, but the rest of `$path` comes in with backslashes, so I didn't want to confuse the handler.

Comment: I also added https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/DOCUMENT-368 to follow up on our website documentation.

Comment: And the changes are live at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_windows_file_paths.html#compensating-for-redirection